# Loop overring variable each time

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through to get a load of long/lats from google directions. However, longArr and latArr only ever have one result in at the end, it's as if the var is getting cleared out each time

```
 function showSteps(directionResult) {
            // For each step, place a marker, and add the text to the marker's
            // info window. Also attach the marker to an array so we
            // can keep track of it and remove it when calculating new
            // routes.
            var myRoute = directionResult.routes[0].legs[0];
            var longArr = "";
            var latArr = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
                var Long = myRoute.steps[i].lat_lngs[0].B;
                var Lat = myRoute.steps[i].lat_lngs[0].k;
                longArr = Long + Long + "|";
                latArr = Lat + Lat + "|";
                alert(longArr);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

                    position: myRoute.steps[i].start_location,
                    map: map
                });
                attachInstructionText(marker, myRoute.steps[i].instructions);

                markerArray[i] = marker;
            }

            $('.long').val(longArr);
            $('.lat').val(latArr);

        }
```

Comment: It's true, everytime you re-declare `longArr` and `latArr`.  Put a `+=` after `longArr` and `latArr` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to declare your arrays as arrays.

```
var longArr = [];
var latArr = [];
```

Then you need to append to them

```
longArr.push(Long + Long);
latArr.push(Lat + Lat);
```

When writing the array out to string use `join`

```
$('.long').val(longArr.join('|'));
$('.lat').val(latArr.join('|');
```

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate with the existing value of the string you have to concatenate the variable too.

Option 1:

```
longArr = longArr + Long + Long + "|" ;
latArr = latArr + Lat + Lat + "|";
```

Option 2:

```
longArr += Long + Long + "|" ;
latArr += Lat + Lat + "|";
```